# Speech To Text In WP7 or Windows 8 Metro

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, microsoft-metro, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I think the question pretty much says it all.

Is there any API by which I can take speech input from the user and then convert it to text? (windows phone 7 or windows 8 metro) ?

Comment: For windows phone, take a look at this [link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Text_to_Speech_in_Windows_Phone_7). For WinRT you can probably do something similar.

Comment: It looks like the Nokia link at http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Text_to_Speech_in_Windows_Phone_7 and the current Microsoft Translator service is Text to Speech and not Speech to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the Hawaii project :-

Speech-to-Text Service
This service takes a spoken phrase and returns text (currently in English only).

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/hawaii/